# cellForRowAtIndexPath - [indexPath row] returning weird numbers when scrolling

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, uitableview

I know there are plenty of other questions ask about [indexPath row] and scrolling, but can anybody help me understand why it is returning weird numbers?  I can't seem to figure out a workaround for the way I have configured my cells:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{


    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ProfileIdentifier";

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];


    if(cell == nil){
        //My custom xib file is named "ProfileCell.xib"
        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProfileCell" owner:self options:nil];
                cell = profileCell;
        self.profileCell = nil;
    }
//name and info are both of type NSArray
    labelName.text = [name objectAtIndex:row];
    labelInfo.text = [info objectAtIndex:row];
    NSLog(@"Row: %d", row);

    return cell;
}
```

The console is returning this when loaded:

2012-08-26 09:09:10.966 Nav[8028:f803] Row: 0

2012-08-26 09:09:10.983 Nav[8028:f803] Row: 1

2012-08-26 09:09:10.986 Nav[8028:f803] Row: 2

2012-08-26 09:09:10.996 Nav[8028:f803] Row: 3

2012-08-26 09:09:10.999 Nav[8028:f803] Row: 4

2012-08-26 09:09:11.002 Nav[8028:f803] Row: 5

2012-08-26 09:09:11.004 Nav[8028:f803] Row: 6

2012-08-26 09:09:11.007 Nav[8028:f803] Row: 7

2012-08-26 09:09:11.010 Nav[8028:f803] Row: 8

2012-08-26 09:09:11.012 Nav[8028:f803] Row: 9

It then returns this when I scroll down to cells off screen:

2012-08-26 09:09:12.354 Nav[8028:f803] Row: 3

2012-08-26 09:09:12.404 Nav[8028:f803] Row: 2

2012-08-26 09:09:12.471 Nav[8028:f803] Row: 1

2012-08-26 09:09:12.622 Nav[8028:f803] Row: 0

My labelName.text and labelInfo.text are changing every time the user scrolls.
However, the only affected cell is the bottom one.  How can I keep the 9th cell's labelName to be consistent with [indexPath row]?

Comment: Shouldn't you be setting cell.labelName.text rather than labelName.text?

Comment: do u have sections in ur tableview?

Comment: @jrturton - don't think so.  All the cells are working as intended.  Only the last cell is changing, which is the problem.

Comment: @tiguero - I only have 1 section, and have declared it as such.

Comment: What what is self.profileCell? Are you saving the created cell across calls and editing the label text of the saved cell (labelName and LabelInfo)? If so, that is the source of your problem.

Comment: @claireware self.profileCell is the outlet for my custom table cell created in a .xib.  I can comment out that line and it would still be the same.  I set it to nil for clean memory management.

Comment: it seems you have not set the any property of `cell` and it seems the `labelName` and `labelInfo` is definitely simple global variables without any connection with your `cell`.

Comment: @holex - That was not the problem.  My labelname and labelinfo are connected.  It is working as intended now. See Answer.

Comment: @Magnum, you've accepted an answer which suggest the same solution, so I guess it **was** your problem.

Comment: @holex Ok, so with the original code, cells 0-8 will initialize properly with the labelName and labelInfo.  Cells 0-8 do not change text.  HOWEVER, cell 9 would constantly change when the table is swiped down.  my labels are connected, but I don't know why tagging the labels resulted differently.  Now it is working as intended, cell 9 no longer changes.  I am still confused however, about why cellForRowAtIndexPath is called when the table is swiped, and why the [indexPath row] returns 3, 2, 1...

Comment: @Magnum, okay, I see. you don't understand why those two solutions (or suggestions) are same. :( never mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured a work-around:

I set each label with a tag.  Then edited the code like so:

```
//labelName.text = [name objectAtIndex:row];
//labelInffo.text = [info objectAtIndex:row];
```

replaced with:

```
UILabel *label;
label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
label.text = [name objectAtIndex:row];
label = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];
label.text = [info objectAtIndex:row];
```

Hope this helps anyone who decides to modify labels via arrays :x

Edit:  I'm not sure why setting tags work, but my original method would still change the labels.  Can someone explain?

Answer (score 1):

this is the proper way to work with custom `UITableViewCell`:

---

in the **.h** file:

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {
    UINib *profileCellNib;
}

// ...

@end
```

---

in your **.m** file:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    profileCellNib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"ProfileCell" bundle:nil];
}

// ...

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"ProfileIdentifier";

    NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];
    UIProfileCell *cell = (UIProfileCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if(cell == nil) cell = [[UINib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

    cell.labelName.text = [name objectAtIndex:row];
    cell.labelInfo.text = [info objectAtIndex:row];

    NSLog(@"Row: %d", row);

    return cell;
}
```

---

I assume the `UIProfileCell` is an inherited class from `UITableViewCell`, maybe you are using another name for your custom cell view in that case you should set the correct name in the `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method instead of mine.

Answer (score 1):

The whole caching mechanism is set up wrong.

The relevant code here:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ProfileCell" owner:self options:nil];
cell = profileCell; // profile cell is most likely nil here, you set cell to nil?
self.profileCell = nil; // if profile cell wasn't nil, it will surely be nil next pass.
```

I bet if you log the initializing code in `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` you'll see that every cell gets recreated instead of being returned from cache. In you situation the initialization should happen only once for the very first cell that is being displayed. For every other cell the design should be retrieved from cache using the  `-dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` method.

Comment: I have declared profileCell in my .h file as my outlet to my table view cell:
    @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableViewController *profileCell;

profileCell is not nil, it returns the cell correctly when with loadNibNamed:@"ProfileCell"